# Synchronization and Mutex

Tags: android, synchronization, location, ipc, mutex

There are 2 android applications: `App1` with `Process1` and `Service1`, `App2` with `Process2` and `Service2`.

There is one more application `AppManager` which is just an independent service called `ManagerService`. `ManagerService` does two things basically:

1. Registers listeners for using sensors on the phone
2. Gets the data with the help of these listener. *Note*: Getting data can take some time.

Now, with defined AIDL, I can bind `Service1` with `ManagerService` and bind `Service2` with `ManagerService`. Both `Service1` and `Service2` now can call the remote method `A(...)` to request registered listeners that is defined in `ManagerService`, and then fetch the shared sensor data which is saved in a list from `ManagerService`.

If now `Service1` is executing the remote method `A(...)` to get sensor data from `ManagerService`, e.g.:

```
List A(...) {
    // ...
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            0, 0, locationListener);
    // ...
    return list;
}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        SaveLocationToList(location);
    }
}
```

How exactly can I guarantee that `Service2` will only request to fetch the sensor data only after `Service1` has finish the above "request-registration-updateList-getList" process?

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why are these three separate apps, if they are so inter-dependent?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for editing and format this post for me...:D I have posted my way down here.

Answer (score 0):

```
List A(...) 
{
    // ...
    synchronized(this)
   {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            0, 0, locationListener);
    // ...
    return list;
   }
}
```